# Determining percentile based on reference table

Tags: r, statistics

I have standardized normal values for heart rates and respiratory rates in children from a recent article.  I copied them into a csv to use as a dataset in R. The data is simply different age ranges (ex 3 months to 6 months, or 1 year to 2 years) and then the heart rate for the 1st percentile, 10th, 25th, 50th, 75th, 90th, 99th percentile for that age range.

I want to compare a patients data with this reference table to tell me what percentile they are at. Since this is a perfectly normal distribution, I don't think its a very hard task to do, but its outside of my R scope and I can't seem to find any good information on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you explained i can suggest this simple function that will input the heart rate and the age range of your patient and return the %percentile based on a normal density of this specific range.

```
my.quantile = function(myrange, heart.rate){
  table <- data.frame('range'= c("range1", "range2", "range3"),
             'mean' = c(120, 90, 60),
             'sd'   = c(12, 15, 30))
  res <- pnorm(q    = heart.rate,
               mean = subset(table, range==myrange)$mean,
               sd   = subset(table, range==myrange)$sd)
  return(res*100)
}

### my.quantile("range1", 140) 
### [1] 95.22096
```

From what you say if it is perfectly normal you just need the mean and variance of each range right? You can adapt it for the respiratory rate.

**EDIT**: in order to retrieve the normal distribution parameters from your quantile table, given the hypothesis that the quantiles you've got are rather precise:

i/  Your mean paramater is exactly the 50th percentile

ii/ You find the standard deviation by taking any other percentile, for instance let's assume your 90th percentile is 73 beats and the 50th is 61 beats:

```
(73-61)/qnorm(0.90)
### [1] 9.36365
```

9.36 is your standard deviation. From here it shouldn't be very hard to automate it.

Note: if your percentile data are not very precise, you may want to repeat the operation for each percentile value and take the average.

Comment: or maybe your difficulty is also to retrieve the means and standard deviation based on the percentiles from your table?

Comment: Thank you very much!!  Excellent!  How can I derive the mean/SD easily from just knowing the quantile data?  I think I can do it the old fashioned way, but I'm sure R has an easy way to calculate it.